# How disable this line on Mui X DataGrid?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

this line!

[image: 1]

i try to override css class by
`.MuiDivider-root{ display: none  }`

it not working

Comment: Please clarify your problem and add more code so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bottom border which comes from `.MuiDataGrid-cell`. Just set it to `none`.